# How to put image below X axis in Chart.js

Tags: jquery, image, charts

I am using Chart.js ([documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/)). This is my code for graph:

```
var ChartData = {
labels : values,
datasets : [{
    fillColor :"rgba(24,121,186,0.62)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(204,204,204,0.34)",
    pointColor : "rgba(24,121,186,0.08)",
    markerShape : "circle",
    pointStrokeColor : "rgba(24,121,186,1)",
    data : graf1,
    title:"2015"},]};
```

As you can see my label is array. "var values = [];".

Is possible to add to "labels" `<div image></div>` below. For example, in my array, I have values ["1:00","2:00","3:00"] so my chart would look like this:

[image: Chart with label text]

And if you would add pictures it would look like this:

[image: Chart with label text and image]

I have try this, but it is not working:

```
labels : values + <div class="img"><img src="http://location.png"></div>
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Realy thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to manipulate the relative (or absolute) positioning with an in-line style?

Comment: no, I did not. So you suggest that is better , that I create below chart "div" that would inline images...

Comment: Better? Maybe, maybe not.  But it should work none the less.  I'm not familiar with chart.js... is the chart size consistently the same?

Comment: Yes, chart is always same size. Not responsive

Comment: then you should be good.  Just wrap the images in a div and add style="position:relative;top:-yyypx;left:-xxxpx;margin-bottom:-yyypx" to the div (replaceing xxx and yyy with appropriate values).  Or, heck, you might even try tabling the whole thing and see what it looks like.

Comment: great, tnx for answer @user3479671 :D

Comment: @DaniKR were you able to add images to labels. I am trying with the above suggestion but not getting it exactly correct. If possible could you please post some sample code

Comment: @ArigatoManga No I did not, my Front-end guy sovled it with CSS